# Node access inside a table with testing library

Tags: eslint, testing-library

I'm doing some testing to make sure that table data is rendered correctly in a table and in the right positions.

```js
    const tableRows = screen.getAllByRole("row");
    expect(tableRows).toHaveLength(2); // Header plus one data row.
    // Column 1 is a toggle icon.
    expect(tableRows[1].querySelector("td:nth-child(2)").textContent).toBe("Hello");
    expect(tableRows[1].querySelector("td:nth-child(3)").textContent).toBe("3 days ago");
    expect(tableRows[1].querySelector("td:nth-child(4)").textContent).toBe("Success");
    expect(tableRows[1].querySelector("td:nth-child(5)").textContent).toBe("EditDelete"); // Edit and Delete buttons.
```

However, es-lint is rightly complaining that I am using node access patterns via
`Avoid direct Node access. Prefer using the methods from Testing Library. eslint(testing-library/no-node-access)`

What's the best way to access nodes in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Es-lint has some rules about this defined [here](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-node-access.md)

Depending on your render function, using [Within](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/) may be an option for you. But for complex examples such as this we can make use of [data-testid](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid/).
In the render function in the component, for each tableRow, you could add an attribute for data-testid and then access this element in the test through `queryByTestId`:

e.g:

```
expect(screen.queryByTestId("table-row-2").textContent).toBe("Hello");
```

Comment: Thanks! ES-Lint is the tool that was complaining about the rule! I thought about data-testid, but feel like it's a hack/shortcut and injects extra tags into the rendered HTML unnecessarily, so was just wondering about the right way to go about targeting the nodes in the table.